# Hide empty category on woocommerce

Tags: categories

Hello i create a function to display list of subcategory on master category page. With my functions now i see also category that no have product (empty). I need hide this empty category..

My master category and list subcategory code

```
              <h1 style="font-size: 36px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 2px;   font-family: 'Oswald';"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo $cat->description ; ?></p>
                <!--<?php if(is_array($parent_categories_ids)){ echo'<pre>',print_r($parent_categories_ids),'</pre>'; }?> -->
            <div class="list">
            <ul>
            <?php foreach($term_children as $child) :
                    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'product_cat' );
            ?>
<?php                 if( $child->count <= 0 ) {
        continue;
    } ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $child, 'product_cat' )?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Code to try hide

```
 <?php // Skip empty terms
        if( $child->count <= 0 ) {
            continue;
        } ?>
```

But not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your code i'm assuming your `$child` is the `id` of an `term`, the term object is being stored in the `$term` variable, so you can do this:

```
<?php if( $term->count > 0 ): ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $child, 'product_cat' )?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```